iPhone (iOS18) often fails to switch Bluetooth audio devices - anyone else seen this?
Ever since I updated to iOS 18, my iPhone often fails to switch bluetooth audio devices. Mostly this means that after I have used my AirPods at the health club (and then put my buds in their case) it does not connect to my Toyota Prius speakers. And after I have used them in my car (and then left the car parked for a few hours), the phone will not connect to my AirPods.
I expect it to connect automatically when I get in the car (it always did before) and to switch to the AirPods when I take them out of the case.
To recover from this, I go through a couple of cycles of:

Turn BT off in settings and then back on.
Select the desired device manually in BT settings.
"Connection failed"
Turn Bluetooth off and back on.
Select desired unit.

It usually works after two iterations. And other times it works fine.
Has anyone else seen this?

Have you tried to disable all apps from Settings > Privacy & Security > Bluetooth?
You can also try to reset network settings, but you'll loose all your Wi-Fi passwords...
